# Database Hsqldb cannot differentiate between date and timestamp

Tags: database, date, hsqldb

[image]

i have been using postgresql to cast current date as date and the result is like`2016-08-08` but when i tried it on hsqldb the result is shown like above
can someone enlighten me about this ? i want to get only the date not the time on hsqldb
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have probably set the Oracle syntax compatibility mode. In the default mode and also in PostgreSQL syntax mode, the result looks like PostgreSQL:

```
C1                         C2                         C3         
-------------------------- -------------------------- ---------- 
2016-08-09 20:57:24.043000 2016-08-09 20:57:24.043000 2016-08-09
```

Comment: ermm sry i dont get what you were trying to explain,
when i was using postgresql to make casting date query i used pg Admin and when i tried it on hsqldb i used sql workbench,
i still dont get it where should i setting oracle syntax can u please explain it for me thanks for helping me

Comment: Try using the HSQLDB DatabaseManager instead and see the result. The connection properties are explained in the Guide http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html#dpc_sql_conformance but you do not need setting any special property to get the correct result from the cast.